# Population standard deviation in meta analysis

Tags: standard-deviation, meta-analysis

Suppose that data from different experiments all come from the same normal distribution (fixed effect). Is it possible to estimate the population standard deviation in a meta-analysis? I have found several papers that report results for the pain VAS (visual analogue scale), can I pool these to get an estimate of the population standard deviation?